# Is that correct result of console screen when i type mongod on console

Tags: mongodb

When I start `mongod` in my console, this screen always shows up.

[image: Is that correct result?]

Is this the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either [`systemLog.destination`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemLog.destination) in the configuration file or [`--logpath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-logpath) or [`--syslog`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-syslog) on the command line.